# InputStream from local xml file in phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I want to get the inputstream from local xml file in javascript in my phonegap app. I am newbie on javascript.So any one can tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supported only in HTML5, link below may help you -

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/